# calling a function to obtain a model field value

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to get a unique value for a field (unique within the db column).

my code (other model fields omitted):

```
class PlatformUserChildren(models.Model):
    dashboard = models.CharField('dashboard URL', max_length=64, unique=True, default=createDashboardCode(self))

    def createDashboardCode(self):
        stringCheck = False
        while stringCheck is False:
            newString = str(uuid.uuid4())[:32]
           doesStringExist = newString in self.dashboard
            if not doesStringExist:
                stringCheck = True
        return newString
```

I'm getting **name 'self' is not defined** as an error.

What should I be passing to the function so that I can check the db column to ensure the value is unique -or- is there a built-in way of doing this?

What I've already tried or looked at:

1. setting `unique=True` for the field and using `default=uuid.uuid4` - that gives me duplicate values and generates a validation error ([SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835069/uuid-as-default-value-in-django-model))
2. I'm aware of [Django 1.8's UUID field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield), however i'm on 1.7

Comment: Setting the field to unique=True should take care for that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#unique

Comment: thanks cezar - I've already tried that and it generates a validation error when it tries to save a duplicate value. I'd like to catch it before then.

Comment: Yes, the documentation also says it will throw an IntegrityError. This is done on database level. If you want to catch the error, than you should wrap the code for insertion of new entries in a try and catch block. Could you please provide the line (or the lines) that generate the error?

Comment: here you go:dashboard = models.CharField('dashboard URL', max_length=64, unique=True, default=str(uuid.uuid4)[:32])

Comment: Unfortunately, there is some misleading. I asked for the code you execute, like `platform = PlatformUserChildren(dashboard='some value')`. This is the line in your model. However now I understand better your problem. What you want is to insert a unique value if the user doesn't enter any value for this field, right? Why wouldn' t you allow `null=True`. That would save you all the efforts. The value must be unique, but it can leave it to NULL.

Comment: I don't expect the customer to enter any values. I want a value to be generated upon a new model instance creation. I.e. New model created and a value is generated for this filed automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the following line (indented for better readability) as you already know and mentioned before:

```
dashboard = models.CharField(
    'dashboard URL',
    max_length=64,
    unique=True,
    default=createDashboardCode(self)
)
```

In this part:

```
default=createDashboardCode(self)
```

you're calling the method `createDashboardCode` with the argument `self`. This is wrong, because you never pass `self` to a method as it is passed by Python. Whenever you call the method `createDashboardCode` you should do it this way:

```
createDashboardCode()
```

That's it, you're not passing the argument `self` explicitly.

You're getting an error "name 'self' is not defined" because `self` is not defined. There is no variable `self` in your code that you can pass to the method.

Now we're one step further, but your problem won't be solved if you just apply this slight change to your code.

The return value from the method `createDashboardCode` will be assigned to `default`. That's not what you really want. You have to assign a reference of the method to `default`:

```
default = createDashboardCode
```

Pay attention to the missing brackets. This will call the method every time a new instance of the model is created

Define a function:

```
def my_function():
    print "hello"
```

and run it in the Python interpreter:

```
# once like this
my_function()
# and again like this
my_function
```

and you'll see the difference. That should help you to better comprehend this issue.

Comment: that solved it @cezar - there are a couple of (other, unrelated) issues with my code but you answered my question. Many thanks :)